# How to prevent (scurrying) animations from pixelation when uploaded to YouTube?

Tags: rendering, animation, blur, compression

I've created an animation in which a hugh quantitiy of small-scale movements are happening at the same time.
The mp4 file, which results from the render process, displays this animation without any problems ... unfortunately, [it blurs / pixelates when uploaded to YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zgf1oPsAw7s&feature=youtu.be&t=16).

[image: comparision between orignal frame and blurry youtube frame.]

I assumed that this is due to YouTube's compression. Therefore I tried to change Blender's output settings so that they meet [YouTube's guidelines](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1722171?hl=en) (bitrate=10k, GOP = half the frame rate, etc).

Unfortunately, increasing the bitrate (up to 85k) or decreasing the keyframe interval had no impact on the pixelation.

The original output settings:

[image: picture of the original output settings]

---

**Is it possible to optimize the Video in a way, that the pixelation is reduced or prevented?**

Comment: Try this tutorial, basically you want to trick youtube into giving you a better codec: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RuctbRXaAI0

Comment: This improved the [video quality](https://imgur.com/a/DkvjXYr) quite a lot! Would you like to post it as an answer so that I can accept it?